# How to build a action in custom connector similar to "Wait for an approval"

Tags: api, power-automate, power-platform, power-automate-custom-connector

I'd like to create my own action in Power Automate by using custom connector, and this action is "wait for an my event complete", which is similar to build-in action "Wait for an approval".  I'd like to make my workflow wait at this action until it complete and get output data for following action.

I'm not sure how to create back-end API for this action, is this a long-life HTTP call or something else?  The waiting period could be days or weeks.

Very appreciate for any hints or opinions.

Comment: You actually don't need a custom connector, you can use the webhook action to achieve this.  You need to make sure you create the back end service that completes the flow by making the call back to trigger the webhook.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-native-webhook

Comment: @Skin Thank you, but the webhook action is Premium, which I can't use.

Comment: Could you use LogicApps in Azure rather than PowerAutomate?  There's no restrictions on connectors in there.

Comment: LogicApp also require license which I don't have...

Comment: No it doesn’t, it’s pay as you go. Azure is open to anyone, you just pay for what you use.